# How to concat two subclassed arrays?

Tags: javascript

I have two array subclasses: Nodes and Beacons.  When I run .concat on two of their instances, it creates a new array with 2 elements: the entire nodes array instance, and the entire beacons array instance.  What should I do to make it work as expected?

Nodes.js

```
mgm.Nodes = function() {
  Array.apply(this, arguments);
  this.fetch();
};

mgm.Nodes.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);
mgm.Nodes.prototype.constructor = mgm.Nodes;

mgm.Nodes.prototype.create = function(data) {
  //mgm.Node is an object and should be fine to replace with Object for testing purposes
  var node = new mgm.Node(data);
  this.push(node);
  return node;
};

mgm.Nodes.prototype.get = function(id) {
};

mgm.Nodes.prototype.fetch = function() {
  var n = 20;
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var data = {
      id: i,
      attributes: {name: undefined,}
    };
    this.create(data);
  }
};

mgm.Nodes.prototype.remove = function(node) {
  return this.splice(this.indexOf(node), 1)[0];
};

mgm.Nodes.prototype.update = function(node) {
  // TODO: bind this to node.on('save')
};
```

Beacons.js

```
mgm.Beacons = function() {
  this.fetch();
};

mgm.Beacons.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);
mgm.Beacons.constructor = mgm.Beacons;

mgm.Beacons.prototype.create = function(data) {
  //mgm.Beacon is an object and should be fine to replace with Object for testing purposes
  var beacon = new mgm.Beacon(data);
  this.push(beacon);
  return beacon;
};

mgm.Beacons.prototype.fetch = function() {
  this.create({x: 200, y: 150, fixed: true, tag: ''});
};
```

Running this results in a length 2 array (expected 21), where the 0th element has a length of 20:

```
var nodes = new Nodes();
var beacons = new Beacons();
console.log(nodes.concat(beacons));
```

Comment: You [cannot subclass `Array`](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It creates a new array with 2 elements: the entire nodes array instance, and the entire beacons array instance.

That's because they are no array instances. See what [the `concat` method](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.4) does to determine whether the to-be-concatenated objects are concatenated item-by-item:

> If the value of the [[Class]] internal property of E is "Array", then
>
> > [iterate E and push each single element]
>
> else [put E as a whole  on the result array]

Your `Beacons` and `Nodes` might inherit from `Array.prototype`, but they are simple objects - no special [[Class]], no auto-adjusting `length` property. Btw, `Array.apply(this, arguments);` does not work as expected, it simply creates a new Array. Use `this.push.apply(this, arguments);`.

> What should I do to make it work as expected?

You can overwrite `concat` with your own implementation:

```
mgm.Nodes.prototype.concat = mgm.Beacons.prototype.concat = function concat(other) {
    var O = Object(this),
        A = new Array(), // new this.constructor() ?
        n = 0,
        items = [O];
    items.push.apply(items, arguments);
    while (items.length > 0) {
        var E = items.shift();
        if (typeof E.length == "number") { // not: Array.isArray(E)
            var k = 0,
                len = E.length;
            while (k < len) {
                var P = ""+k;
                if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(E, P)) {
                    var subElement = E[P];
                    A[n] = subElement;
                    n++;
                }
                k++;
            }
        } else { // E is not Array-like
            A[n] = E;
            n++;
        }
    }
    return A;
};
```

Comment: +1. It is unfortunate but Arrays were implemented on the basis of special magic rather than in-language object features. So there's not much you can do to extend them and there isn't really any advantage from inheriting their prototype.

Comment: @bobince: The `length` property does not seem to be definable in terms of the current language - hopefully harmony changes this. Still, inheriting from `Array.prototype` brings us lots of helper functions that work flawlessly on array-like objects - `concat` is the only exception I found that checks the [[Class]].

Comment: Most of those have limited value from my point of view, though, given that they naturally output plain `Array`. For example if I do `beacons.slice(1)` I don't get a sub-`Beacons` object.